# How to create a Regex expression so that it accepts everything but a 4-digit number?

Tags: java, regex

So in my code if the user enters in a 4-digit number then it does not go into the while loop but if they do not enter in a 4-digit number then it should.

This is what I have got so far but it isn't working for me:

```
while (num1.matches("^[0-9]{4}"))
```

From this code I expect a number like '9876' to not go into the while loop but a number like '123' to go into it.

N.B. This is for homework

Comment: Would "0001" be fine?

Comment: No it has to be a number like 3005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex `^[0-9]{4}` matches any number that STARTS with 4 digits. Add a `$` at the end to fix that.

Tests: [link](https://regex101.com/r/SgyKIp/1).

If you need to match everything except that, simply negate the condition:

```
while (!num1.matches("^[0-9]{4}$"))
```

**EDIT**: If you need to avoid 0-leading numbers this regex should be fine: `^[1-9][0-9]{3}$`

Tests: [link](https://regex101.com/r/SgyKIp/2).

Comment: Ok, I will combine it with what you suggets earlier on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Boolean pattern = Pattern.matches("[0-9]{4}", "ur input should be in string (e.g) "1234");
System.out.println(pattern);

hope this resolves ur problem